# Show content on only one page

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, ofbiz, apache-fop

I have three contents to render PDF(in sequence): `C1`, `C2` and `C3`.

`C1` and `C3` can be rendered by more than one page.
`C2` need only one page.

The problem is the `C3` render on the page of `C2`.

Is there any options or configurations to the page of `C2` show only the content of `C2`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'contents'? Content streams? XObjects?

Comment: I mean content is text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer is based on the premise you are using [XSL-FO](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/), deduced from the presence of the [apache-fop](/questions/tagged/apache-fop) tag)

If you use a different `fo:page-sequence` for each section of content, you are guaranteed that each one will begin at the beginning of a new page, even if the previous page would still have available space:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        ...
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
        ... C1 ...
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
        ... C2 ...
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="pages">
        ... C3 ...
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

You can also use the properties `break-before="page"` or `break-after="page"` on `fo:block` elements to force page breaks, but I think the previous solution is more elegant.